# Path to static files after packaging

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-builder, react-boilerplate, electron-packager

Hello guys i have a question about this https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager electron packager, as i am understood correctly everything what i've made compiled to the asar archive, and the second thing in my case packager took the production build of webpack to make .dmg file ( i am working with this boilerplate https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate). Question is: i have simple JSON file with dummy data, but after packaging i have no idea what path to this file i should use. I've tried to use npm module to unpack asar archive and see what happens inside and i didn't see anything, after i've tried to work with extraResources but it didn't helps me at all, because after it compiled i didn't see the file in the archive. I can't understand what i've missed. Images working great and i don't need to change path to them.